# What would the evaluation order of x = x++ + ++x; be?

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could anyone explain these undefined behaviors (i = i++ + ++i , i = i++, etc…)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc)

In Java the evaluation order is specified to be left-to-right.  Is this the case for C and C++ as well, or is it implementation dependent?  I do remember that the evaluation order is unspecified for function arguments, but what about sub-expressions?

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826414/whats-the-value-of-i-i-closed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788696/how-the-code-behaves-different-for-java-and-c-compiler

Comment: lol. The mod mod-closed his own question :D

Comment: @bk1e: Thanks for the links.  I had a feeling this would be covered here before, but it didn't come up when I asked the question.  I figured the quickest way to find the original would be to just ask. :)

Comment: @Earlz: Once somebody pointed out it's a dupe I pretty much had to.  It wouldn't be right for me to leave it open just because it's mine. :)

Comment: @Prasoon: I should hope so ! :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is unspecified which of the arguments to `+` is evaluated first - but that doesn't even matter, because in C and C++, modifying the same object twice without an intervening sequence point is completely undefined behaviour.

Here you're modifying `x` *three* times without an intervening sequence point, so you're well into *here be dragonnes* territory ;)

---

The relevant part of the C99 standard is "6.5 Expressions":

> 2 Between the previous and next
>   sequence point an object shall have
>   its stored value modified at most once
>   by the evaluation of an expression.
>   Furthermore, the prior value shall be
>   read only to determine the value to be
>   stored.

and

> 3 The grouping of operators and
>   operands is indicated by the
>   syntax. Except as specified later
>   (for the function-call (), &&, ||, ?:,
>   and comma operators), the order of
>   evaluation of subexpressions and the
>   order in which side effects take place
>   are both unspecified.

---

It's possible to write legal code that demonstrates the unspecified order of evaluation - for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(void)
{
    puts("foo");
    return 1;
}

int bar(void)
{
    puts("bar");
    return 2;
}

int main()
{
    int x;

    x = foo() + bar();
    putchar('\n');

    return x;
}
```

(It is unspecified whether you get output of `foobar` or `barfoo`).

Answer (score 4):

C++03 Standard 5.4

> Except where noted, the order of
>   evaluation of operands of individual
>   operators and subexpressions of
>   individual expressions, and the order
>   in which side effects take place, is
>   unspecified.53) Between the previous
>   and next sequence point a scalar
>   object shall have its stored value
>   modified at most once by the
>   evaluation of an expression.
>   Furthermore, the prior value shall be
>   accessed only to determine the value
>   to be stored. The requirements of this
>   paragraph shall be met for each
>   allowable ordering of the
>   subexpressions of a full expression;
>   otherwise the behavior is undefined.

... hence, undefined and implementation dependant.

Answer (score 3):

The C standard does not guarantee that the post-increment will actually "happen" after the pre-increment. So that is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

That's not a valid C statement, so it doesn't make sense to talk about the evaluation order.

Comment: What do you mean by "valid"? It successfully compiles in gcc and g++.

Comment: Whether or not a file is successfully compiled by gcc has nothing to do with whether or not it contains valid C statements.  The C standard determines what is valid C, not one compiler.

Comment: This statement is syntactically valid, although semantically incorrect as it causes undefined behaviour.