# Functioning of increment operator in this case

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could anyone explain these undefined behaviors (i = i++ + ++i , i = i++, etc…)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc)

I have this code but i'm not getting how its functioning.

```
main()
{
 int i=1;
 i= ++i + ++i + ++i;
 printf("%d",i);
}
```

I tried to compile it  and im getting the output 10 but i've no idea how. 
What I figured out is the two ++i are getting assigned the value 3 and the one ++i is getting the value 4, before the addition operation is performed. I cant figure out how increment operator is working in this case. Plz help me out with this.

Comment: -1. Please use the search box at the top of the site in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is *[undefined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)* .. there are a ***lot*** of posts similar to this if you search on SO.

For instance [What would the evaluation order of x = x++ + ++x; be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367969/what-would-the-evaluation-order-of-x-x-x-be?lq=1) or [Why are these constructs (using ++) undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc) and more.

Finally, just an opinion/comment: I don't think anyone would advocate writing that type of code as it's also hard to understand (hence the reason for your question).

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you're not supposed to do that. Basically, don't modify a value more than once inside of the same expression. To do otherwise invokes "undefined behavior", which is a fancy way of saying "the compiler makes no guarantees of what will happen.

(Technically, the rule is don't modify a value more than once between the same [sequence points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point))